# When to use true and when to use Boolean.TRUE?

Tags: java, boolean, optional-chaining

I had written a code of which a rough snippet is as follows:

```
boolean isCalledFromAction = Optional.ofNullable(requestParams.get(IS_CALLED_FROM_ACTION))
                             .map(val -> true)
                             .orElse(false);
```

My team lead said to always use existing classes and insisted to use `Boolean` class like below:

```
boolean isCalledFromAction = Optional.ofNullable(requestParams.get(IS_CALLED_FROM_ACTION))
                             .map(val -> Boolean.TRUE)
                             .orElse(Boolean.FALSE);
```

My question is I see Boolean.TRUE will make unnecessary a Boolean type object. When to use true and when to use Boolean.TRUE? Why in first place, `Boolean.java` class contains a wrapper object for true and false? I mean, they have auto-boxing so they can directly do like `Boolean x = true;` instead of `Boolean x = Boolean.TRUE`.

I have read answers on existing questions on SO related to performance but here I am interested in their usage scenarios.

Comment: "My question is I see `Boolean.TRUE` will make unnecessary a `Boolean` type object." It's a static constant. It's only instantiated once anyway.

Comment: `Boolean` objects can be null. Therefore, I find best never to use them

Comment: Regardless, you're ignoring the result of the get method here. So, is there not a method `requestParams.has`?

Comment: Perhaps you should state the exact type of whatever is returned from your call `requestParams.get(IS_CALLED_FROM_ACTION)`.

Comment: @BasilBourque The type returned by `requestParams.get(IS_CALLED_FROM_ACTION)` is a string. If it is not null, I want to set `isCalledFromAction` to true.

Comment: @GAURAVKABRA Then simplify your code to merely `Objects.nonNull ( requestParams.get( IS_CALLED_FROM_ACTION ) )`. See last section added to [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75421786/642706).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Constant, just one immutable object

You asked:

> My question is I see `Boolean.TRUE` will make unnecessary a `Boolean` type object.

No, multiple objects are *not* created.

As [commented by Culloca](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75421716/when-to-use-true-and-when-to-use-boolean-true#comment133078334_75421716), `Boolean.TRUE` is a constant, referring to a singe object instantiated once when the class loads. As an [immutable object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object), there is no need to have more than one.

Let’s [look at the implementation](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Boolean.java) found in the open source code at the [OpenJDK](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK) project.

```
public static final Boolean FALSE = new Boolean(false);
```

The `static` means an instance is created when the class loads. The `final` means the reference named `FALSE` will never be re-assigned to another object. So one, and only one, object.

## Avoid excessive auto-boxing

You are right to be concerned about unnecessary [auto-boxing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boxing_(computer_science)#Autoboxing). Boxing is not magic; it takes CPU cycles to execute.

Going out of your way to use `Boolean.FALSE` where you know the primitive `false` is needed is pointless and a bit silly.

Such a practice is often harmless. If the code is infrequently executed, then you’ll see no significant impact on performance. And in some situations I would guess that the compiler might optimize away the boxing, though that is just a guess on my part.

FYI… Work is underway by the Java team to blur the sharp distinction between primitives and objects created by Java’s two parallel [type systems](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system). So the nature and impact of boxing may change in future versions of Java.

## No need for `Optional`

Your code is overly elaborate.

[You commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75421716/when-to-use-true-and-when-to-use-boolean-true?noredirect=1#comment133083358_75421716):

> The type returned by `requestParams.get(IS_CALLED_FROM_ACTION)` is a string. If it is not null, I want to set `isCalledFromAction` to true.

Change this:

```java
boolean isCalledFromAction = Optional.ofNullable(requestParams.get(IS_CALLED_FROM_ACTION))
                             .map(val -> true)
                             .orElse(false);
```

… to use [`Objects.nonNull`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#nonNull(java.lang.Object)):

```java
boolean isCalledFromAction = 
    Objects
    .nonNull ( 
        requestParams.get( IS_CALLED_FROM_ACTION ) 
    ) ;
```

Answer (score 2):

## At first something general

The main difference between `boolean` and `Boolean` is that a `Boolean` can be null, while a `boolean` cannot. So when you have a check `if(a) {...}`, with a being a `Boolean`, this might lead to a nullpointer exception. In this case, you would prefer to have `if(Boolean.TRUE.equals(a)) {...}`, because the `equals` method of `Boolean` would return false in case a is null.

## Your specific case

What you suggested there is equivalent to

```
isCalledFromAction = Optional.ofNullable(requestParams.get(IS_CALLED_FROM_ACTION)).isPresent();
```

Not that `isPresent` actually returns a boolean and not a Boolean, as do most of the JDK internal methods that I've come across. Apart of that, I would say using `true` or `false` vs. `Boolean.TRUE` or `Boolean.FALSE` shouldn't make a real difference in most of the cases and might even be considered a matter of taste. In a large project, though, you would want to use one or the other consistently to not end up with a mess.